# Shapely/Pyproj transformation throws OverflowError - determining length of LineString

Tags: python, shapely, pyproj

I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook and deleted code I thought I didn't need the other. Now I get an overflow error, when running the notebook. I'm pretty sure the code used to work just fine and the problem is caused by me stupidly deleting stuff.

Anyway, I can't seem to find what is missing and would really appreciate help. I'm using a list with coordinates, convert them to a linestring and then transform them. Finally, I lookup the length.

```
import pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import LineString

route = [[41.875562, -87.624421], [29.949932, -90.070116], [40.712728, -74.006015]]

ls = LineString(route) 

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857'))

ls_metric = transform(project.transform, ls) 

ls_metric_length = round(ls_metric.length / 1000)
```

This returns

> OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

The problem arises already with ls_metric which doesn't generate a LineString.

Comment: can you show the error stack?

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and got this warning:

```
FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated.
'<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method
```

Sure enough I changed the pyproj **Transformer** and got a result:

```
project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:3857'))
```

gives a length of **3984 km**.
I used the latest versions in a venv:

```
pyproj==2.6.0
Shapely==1.7.0
```

The warning above also gives another important note regarding [axis order changes](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6); in short:

```
pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326') works with [lat,lng], [lat,lng] ...
pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326') works with [lng,lat], [lng,lat] ...
```

the first one being the preferred way while the second is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is still not working on my notebook though.
I'm beginning to think that something must be wrong with my installation...

Comment: I just tried it in a new Jupyer notebook and worked; maybe your notebook is using old(er) packages.

Comment: For the axis order changes, you can pass in 'always_xy=True' when creating the transformer.

Comment: Hi @lonut Ticus Could please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668657/why-i-am-receiving-infinity-infity-in-linestring